# CSW GetRecords ogc filter propertyIsLike and issues with '-' in the searched field

Tags: geonetwork, csw

We have a Geonetwork 3.10.6.0 instance and have a front end that issues csw getRecords requests with a user input search string. The getRecords requests match against the title field in the metadata records. It can look like anything really. The requests look like

```
      <csw:Query typeNames="csw:Record">
    <csw:ElementSetName>full</csw:ElementSetName>
    <csw:Constraint version="1.1.0">
     <ogc:Filter><ogc:PropertyIsLike matchCase="false" wildCard="%" singleChar="_" escapeChar="!">
            <ogc:PropertyName>title</ogc:PropertyName>
            <ogc:Literal>%3D-%</ogc:Literal>
          </ogc:PropertyIsLike></ogc:Filter>
```

And they return the expected metadatarecords whenever the title does not include a hyphen directly after another character and another character following. The above for instance works but if the literal is changed to `%3D-b%` where the actual title of the record is `3D-byggnader` then 0 records match.

`Administrativa namn, punkter - Fastighetskartan` (and any substring of it) matches a record with that exact title but `Administrativa lokaler - Träd- och parkförvaltningen` matches 0 records. (The hyphen after the 'd' might look slightly different from the preceding one but they are both `U+002D : HYPHEN-MINUS {hyphen, dash; minus sign}` when copy pasted and looked up.

Can I alter the PropertyIsLike params to achieve what I'd like or does anyone know why the hyphen/dash in the described scenarios makes the pattern matching fail?

Comment: try adding a `\ ` before the `-` in case it is confusing the Java regex engine, but you'd really have to check the code to tell how the pattern is generated

Comment: Adding `\\` to before the troublesome - or its following character or both seems to produce no different result. I can re-formulate the code that generates the request however necessary, part of the post looks like the above quoted xml, however I cannot manually create a post request that produces the expected result so it has less to do with the client and more to do with geonetwork's csw endpoint I think. If you meant Geonetwork's code then it's on Github; I'm not Java-proficient but could always update to the latest 3.10.x .

Comment: shouldn't you use "!" as the escape character not "\" as indicated in the `<ogc:PropertyIsLike` parameters

Comment: nmtoken: sure, I assumed he meant the currently employed escapechar. So this :


```lang-xml
<ogc:Filter><ogc:PropertyIsLike matchCase="false" wildCard="%" singleChar="_" escapeChar="!">
                <ogc:PropertyName>title</ogc:PropertyName>
                <ogc:Literal>%3d!-b%</ogc:Literal>
              </ogc:PropertyIsLike></ogc:Filter>
```
 produces 0 hits